# Creating a Post, can authors be ordered by last name?

Tags: posts

When I create a post, the author dropdown/select seems to order authors by the first letter of the full display name.

Is there a bit of code for functions.php that would order this dropdown by last name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one example how we can modify the order of users in the dropdowns on the `post.php` and `post-new.php` pages (PHP 5.4+):

```
/**
 * wp_dropdown_users - modify ordering on post.php and post-new.php
 */
add_filter( 'wp_dropdown_users_args', function( Array $query_args, Array $args )
{
    // Nothing to do if we're not on post.php and post-new.php
    if( ! did_action( 'load-post.php' ) && ! did_action( 'load-post-new.php' ) )
        return $query_args;

    // Modify the user query - Adjust to your needs!
    $query_args['meta_key'] = 'last_name';
    $query_args['orderby']  = [ 'meta_value' => 'ASC', 'display_name' => 'ASC' ];

    return $query_args;

}, 10, 2 );
```

Here we query users that have the `last_name` meta key and order first by the `last_name` and then `display_name`.

Hope you can adjust it to your needs!

Comment: This was very helpful.  It didn't quite work for the last name order, but did work for ordering by username.   By formatting usernames as 'last name_first name,' made this work to order by username and not by the display name.   So, the second query line is $query_args ['orderby'] = [ 'username' => 'ASC' ] ;  .